# Valid Triangle: Error getting sum of two sides less then the third?

Tags: kotlin, if-statement

Getting wrong output While trying to check the validity of a triangle where condition is ** sum of two side should be greater then the third** on 3 random integers between 0 to 20. Below output suggest two sides are greater then the third but showing "Not a valid triangle".

```
fun main() {
var a = (Math.random() * 20).toInt()
var b = (Math.random() * 20).toInt()
var c = (Math.random() * 20).toInt()
var validTriangle = "length $a,$b,$c"
if (a + b > c && b + c > a && a + c > b) {
    println("Valid Triangle")
} else {
    println("Not a valid Triangle")
}
println(validTriangle)

The below output suggests sum of two side(13,6) should be > third side(4)
which is 19 so answer should be  "valid triangle" but it is not showing that
```

**Output:**

```
 Not a valid Triangle
 length 13,6,4
```

Comment: But 6 + 4 ≯ 13…

Comment: The code is correct. It's certainly possible to draw a triangle with sides of 4, 6 and 13 units, but not on a flat plane :)

Comment: @gidds output suggests sum of two side(13,6) should be > third side(4)
which is 19 so answer should be  "valid triangle" but it is not showing that

Comment: But for a valid triangle _each_ of the three pairs of lengths must sum to more than the remaining one: you'd need 13 + 6 > 4 (true), 6 + 4 > 13 (false), _and_ 13 + 4 > 6 (true).  And that's what your code is testing.  It correctly shows that this can't be a valid triangle.

Comment: @gidds i got it finally. all the three pairs should satisfy "sum of two side " greater then "third side". so all should be true for the valid triangle.  Thanks !